Identify file concerned by PHP error "Lock not acquired"
I'm using php-fpm in combination with Apache on Debian 12
In my apache logs, I see this kind of error
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Lock not acquired 

This is probably linked to the Apparmor profile I've defined.
I'm trying to identify which file is concerned to fix it (in my Apparmor profile or somewhere else if it's not related to Apparmor).
I was able to activate PHP error logging by adding those settings in the php-fpm pool
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool.error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

I unfortunately doesn't get more info as this log file contains exactly the same message
I have also tried to increase the global error logging verbosity into /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf.
Unfortunately, it only resuls by adding useless debugging info /var/log/php8.2-fpm.log
The error_reporting setting in php.ini is defined like this
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING

I really don't know what I could do to debug this

I have fixed my apparmor profile but I still don't know which files were affected
